# Why $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

> I'm tring to know why $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Can you help me with a proof or showing me some references, please.

Comment: Finding the roots of a polynomial sometimes helps.

Comment: *Prove* is the verb, *proof* is the noun.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual trick is to look instead at $f(x+1) = \frac{(x+1)^p-1}{x}$. Since the binomial coefficients are divisible by $p$, this polynomial is [Eisenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) at $p$, and therefore irreducible. Thus $f$ is also irreducible.

Comment: this is perfect :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Indeed! But I'm not claiming parenthood. :)